# Jetty taking too much time to start

Tags: java, windows, jetty

I have JRE 1.8.0_40 and Jetty 9.2.10. I am simply doing `java -jar start.jar`.  This take 35 sec to 42 sec to start Jetty. Is it ok in case of newer version of Jetty because older one (Jetty - 7.0.0) took only 2 to 3 sec to start Jetty

Platform : Windows 2008 R2 server

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the slow startup in Jetty 9.2.10 is caused by annotation scanning.  This wiki page describes the problem and provides a remedy:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment

As the page says:

> *"Since servlet 3.0 (**supported by jetty-8.x**), there has been the added requirement that both container and webapp jars can be scanned."*

---

Some further research suggests that there are other plausible explanations.  If the solution in the above wiki page doesn't help, I suggest that you:

- Turn on verbose logging an try to narrow down what phase of the startup is taking the time.
- Attach a profiler and find out where the startup code hotspots are.
- Use external performance monitoring (e.g. the Windows Task Manager) to see if the JVM is busy or idle during the long startup.

These should give you some clues to help you / us diagnose the real problem.

Comment: Jetty Dev here.  This is the correct answer.  Also note that startup in a production sense can be improved by [doing the annotation scanning at build-time producing results in the WAR that the `quickstart` module can use](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html) to vastly speed up production startup (often under 400ms).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have many web applications/ big application there?
It could be a problem of slow unwrapping a big war file.